# Once we pinned one hash plan for SQL ID in Oracle, will Oracle change the plan in the future?

Tags: oracle, hash, profile

Once we pinned one hash plan for SQL ID to a particular SQL profile, will Oracle change the plan in the future? E.g. if we are doing some DB upgrade or a new code fix on the DB side? When are the pinned plans getting changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql profile might use different plan if it see some change in data distribution or new indexes.If you don't want any change in plans use stored outline.

Comment: Thank you mohsen.b
Can you please provide some example how to use stored outline for pinning the sql hash value ?

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle figures out that there is a potentially better execution path available, the optimizer may select that plan instead.

So, yes, it is possible that Oracle may not use the pinned plan.

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_profiles.htm#TGSQL598):

> Unlike hints and stored outlines, SQL profiles do not tie the
>   optimizer to a specific plan or subplan. SQL profiles fix incorrect
>   estimates while giving the optimizer the flexibility to pick the best
>   plan in different situations.